Air_MultiAvailability_19.1 AMADEUS
How can I retrieve more than 10 flight information in the response? Currently, I'm only able to receive 10 flight info each time I make a request, but there are more than 10 flights available on certain days
Here is my request
<Air_MultiAvailability xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/SATRQT_19_1_1A">
      <messageActionDetails>
        <functionDetails>
          <businessFunction>1</businessFunction>
          <actionCode>44</actionCode>
        </functionDetails>
      </messageActionDetails>
      <requestSection>
        <availabilityProductInfo>
          <availabilityDetails>
            <departureDate>200524</departureDate>
          </availabilityDetails>
          <departureLocationInfo>
            <cityAirport>TPE</cityAirport>
          </departureLocationInfo>
          <arrivalLocationInfo>
            <cityAirport>ICN</cityAirport>
          </arrivalLocationInfo>
        </availabilityProductInfo>
        <qualifiedConnectionOption>
          <connectionOption>
            <firstConnection>
              <indicatorList>N</indicatorList>
            </firstConnection>
          </connectionOption>
        </qualifiedConnectionOption>
        <airlineOrFlightOption>
          <flightIdentification>
            <airlineCode>6x</airlineCode>
          </flightIdentification>
        </airlineOrFlightOption>
        <availabilityOptions>
          <typeOfRequest>TN</typeOfRequest>
        </availabilityOptions>
      </requestSection>
    </Air_MultiAvailability>


After doing first request, you can search for more availability by doing next call using this request.
<Air_MultiAvailability xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/SATRQT_19_1_1A">
    <messageActionDetails>
        <functionDetails>
            <actionCode>55</actionCode>
        </functionDetails>
    </messageActionDetails>
</Air_MultiAvailability>

